# Call function on aggregated subsets (.SD) which does not produce a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to group my data.table and feed the resulting subsets into a function. This function returns a list of data.tables.

I can imagine that calling the function directly in `j`on `.SD` won't work, because the result is not a data.table, atomic list or vector. However, I was hoping to make use of .SD and call the function in a vectorized fashion (I hope that's the correct term here), instead of looping over the grouping variable, subsetting the data in the loop and calling the function.

Reproducible example:

```
f <- function(dt_subset) {
  l <- list(dt_subset)
  return(l)
}

dt <- data.table(group = rep(c(1,2,3), 3),
                 name = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 9)],
                 value = runif(9))

# obviously this won't work:
result <- dt[, f(.SD), by = group]
```

Naive solution (shows the desired output):

```
result <- list()
for (g in unique(dt$group)) {
  dt_sub <- dt[group == g]
  result <- c(result, f(dt_sub))
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `?split()`(i.e., `split(dt, dt$group)`)? Or is this more of a conceptual question?

Comment: yes! thanks for pointing that out. although it is a slightly different question: in my actual use case I have two variables to group by – can I do this with split?

Comment: Please read `?split.data.table`.

Comment: got it. sorry. thanks for your help!

Comment: No need to say sorry, glad it works for you!